# Extract from directory inside zip file

Tags: python, python-3.x, zip

My existing code (a section) is loacted at the bottom of this post.

What I would like to do is extract all of the files from a directory *inside* of a zip file. Not the whole contents of a zip file, just the files in a directory (`/theme_files/`) that's inside of a zip. I have already imported the neccesary libraries.

Extract the files from `[filename].tpk/theme_files` into `./workspace/[output]/`

(`.tpk` = `.zip`)

```
theme_zip = zipfile.ZipFile(current_dir + "/themes/" + theme_name + ".tpk", 'r')
theme_zip.extractall(output_dir)
theme_zip.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for item in (f for f in theme_zip.filelist if 'theme_files/' in f.filename):
    theme_zip.extract(item, output_dir)
```

Comment: This only works to copy the `theme_files` folder into the output. any idea how to extract the content of `theme_files` into the output?

Comment: It should extract the folder and everything it contains. Is that not happening for you?

Comment: Nope. It extracts the whole folder and puts it in `output_dir`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`ZipFile.extractall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) and set the `path` and `members` args using a list comprehension on the filenames returned from [`ZipFile.namelist()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist):

```
import zipfile 

output_dir = './workspace/[output]/'
file = current_dir + "/themes/" + theme_name + ".tpk"

with zipfile.ZipFile(file, 'r') as f:
    files = [n for n in f.namelist() 
                   if n.startswith('/theme_files/') and not n.endswith('/')]
    f.extractall(path=output_dir , members=files)
```

Answer (score -1):

Search the file names in the specific subfolders with regex. + Extract them file by file:

```
with open('<file-name>.zip', 'rb') as f:
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(f)
    for file in [m.group() for m in (re.search(r'/theme/(.+)', file) for file in file_list) if m]:
        zf.extract(file)
```